# How to find the coordinate of idea position in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In Gnuplot, it always cost me lots of time to find the idea coordinate in
screen coordinate system to put a label. Is there some good idea how to do
it fast?

I was thinking of putting a coordinate grid in screen coordinate system, but 
do not know how to do it, maybe someone could provide a solution or better 
idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the screen coordinates? You could use `first` or `graph` as coordinate system for positioning

Comment: Thanks, the first coordinate could help by the "set grid". But I do not know how the graph coordinate would help.

Comment: The reason I use screen coordinate is that I was using multiplot and I want to add all labels in one place in the code in a uniform way.